# render dump() in created Twig_Environment

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I try use debug extension in new  Twig_Environment here is example

```
$twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$twig->addExtension( new \Twig_Extension_Debug());
$rendered = $twig->render(
"out : {{ dump(array) }}",
array("array" => ['aa','bb'])
);

die($rendered);
```

give my out:

why dump() not work ?

Answer (score 2):

ok i found

```
$twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String(),array(
            'debug' => true,
        ));
```